# Relationship between Geneva and gin?

Tags: etymology, latin

I've been curiously browsing wikipedia today. The word Geneva, besides the city and Canton, is also used to refer to a type of Gin that's made there, and to any other kind of Gin as a generified word.

Based on my "research", gin is named after juniper bushes, which are used in its flavoring.

One might think that there's a casual relationship between the names gin and Geneva, but Wikipedia says that the "Gen" in Geneva comes from a bend in the river in that city.

Is it a coincidence that Geneva sounds similar to gin while also referring to gin?

Comment: To add to your list of coincidences: In Spanish, the word ginebra refers to both the drink and the city.

Answer (score 25):

Gin is abbreviation from *genever*, originally Dutch, where the word means "juniper".  The original drink was made from fermented juniper berries in the Netherlands. The word *genever* (juniper) derives from Latin *iūniperus* via its French version *genevre*.  Geneva is ultimately from Latin *Genāva,* with the etymology you pointed, and unrelated to *iūniperus*.

That said, the similarity between the two words led to people making puns and jokes even in the 17th century, like "reading Geneva print" meaning "to get drunk".

Source: OED.

Comment: The pun rests on the fact that Geneva was the seat  of a (relatively) free press, which published many inflammatory books.

Comment: As I understand things, juniper berries are added to give gin its distinctive flavour, and are _not_ the source of alcohol. That is, juniper berries are not fermented.

Comment: @tomd With modern gin, yes (with the addition of extra herbs, too, in the British style). The original Dutch *genever* spirit (as described in 1606) was however distilled from fermented berries (as opposed to juniper flavour added later to grain spirits), without herbals. (OED)

Comment: @tomd "The original Geneva was made in Holland by grinding berries with the malt before fermentation, and fermenting the whole together, by which the spirit was flavoured with the juniper from the beginning" (Thomas Webster, *An Encyclopædia of Domestic Economy*, 1844)

Comment: As regards the Webster quote, I agree entirely.  But it is the malt, and the malting process, that produces the glucose (grape sugar) that is anaerobically converted by yeast into alcohol (ethanol).  The fact that juniper berries are there from the beginning does not change that, but may give rise to distinctive congeners. The same surely applies to the OED quote. AFAIK, juniper berries (strictly speaking a cones) do not contain grape sugar, or any source of  glucose, and while they may be present in the fermentation mix, there is always another source of glucose (grapes, for example).